# FE 93 error on Miele Induction cooktop

Tags: appliances

When I turn the cook top on, after a few seconds it displays

```
F E
9 3
```

None of the touch buttons respond, and removing the power source for one minute and trying again, does not help.

Answer (score 1):

This error was immediately solved by turning off my overhead lights on my range hood.

I think the touch buttons may be light sensitive and don't like too much.

Answer (score 1):

Error FE 93 was resolved by turning off my overhead lights on my cooking hood.

I guess the touch buttons may be light sensitive.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.